# Can we "say" that standard built-in javascript objects are part of web APIs?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

If we take as an example of an web API `AudioContext`, we can see that this is part of the `window` global object, but all the other standard built-in objects are part of the same `window`, so can we say that from this point, `Object` is a web API?

**EDIT:**

I am talking about the browser context:

```
window.hasOwnProperty('Object')
```

returns **true**, so I got confused.

Comment: "Web APIs" is an informal term with various different meanings in different contexts (you've tagged this question with two *completely different* contexts!), and even within many of those this would be a matter of opinion.  This question is off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `Object` is a **[built-in type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)** specified within the **[ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)**. `window` is not part of that specification.

> At a very basic level, if an object is defined in ECMAScript, then it
>   is native and not part of a WebAPI. WebAPI's are objects provided by a
>   user-agent that native JavaScript can access.

You can actually run JavaScript outside of a browser, using node.js and in that case, you still have access to `Object`, because it's not provided by the host application - it's native to the language.

Comment: yes I know that we can run on the server, but I am talking about a specific context, that's the browser context, of rendering APIs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API. Also, why do you say that Object is not attached to the window at all when window.hasOwnProperty('Object') returns true...?

Comment: I mis-spoke. What I meant to say was that `window` "has a" property called "Object", but `window` is not a native JavaScript object. It is not part of the ECMAScript language.

Comment: let me say what I've understood so far, `window` is a web API(object) and this "has a" property called "Object". Then what is this _Object_ stored for? As I know is the same as the native **ES Object**. So if this Object is the actual ES Object, but is part of a web API object, then what that means?

Comment: Actually, `window` is not a Web API. This gets pretty convoluted, but `window` is the top-level object in the "Browser Object Model" or (BOM), which is a non-standard API that has become a "de-facto" standard over the years. Many Web APIs (like `geolocation`, for example) are objects that have been standardized and attached as properties of BOM objects (`geolocation` is actually: `navigator.geolocation` even though `navigator` itself is not a standard).

Comment: It comes down to standards vs. built-in objects. `Object` is built-in, so it is not a Web API. `window` is not built-in to JS and is not standardized, so it is not a Web API, however other objects that are attached to `window` (or other BOM objects) have been standardized but, because they are not part of the JS standard, and are provided to the JS runtime, they are Web APis.

Comment: That said, I understand that the **ES Object** is "attached" to the `window` object aside with other webAPIs like `navigator`!? Therefore, these two are "attached in parallel"?

Comment: The fact that `window` has an `Object` property is more a function of compatibility than anything else. There is no standard that says that `window` must have this property. It is implemented by the browser vendors.

Comment: Sorry, again, no. `navigator` itself is not a Web API (it's not a standard). `geolocation` is a Web API that you access via `navigator`.

Comment: Yeah, whatever, it could be anything: `AudioContext`, etc, anyway, now I came to realize how all these "are implemented" / works. 10x!